# Passing LocalContext via not @Composable function while working with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

This function works;

```
@Composable
fun writeTextData(){

   val cx = LocalContext.current
   var textData = ""

   // Constructs text data
   textData += ...
   ...

    FileWorks().writeText(cx, "setup", "setup", content = textData)

}
```

This is the class we are keeping file stuff;

```
class FileWorks {

  fun writeText(context: Context, dirName: String, fileName: String, content: String ){

    val path = context.filesDir

    val letDirectory = File(path, dirName)

    val file = File(letDirectory, fileName)


    val isNewFileCreated :Boolean = file.createNewFile()

    if(isNewFileCreated){

        println("$fileName is created successfully.")

    } else{

        println("$fileName already exists.")

    }

    file.writeText(content)


 }

 ...

}
```

But I am unable to use function when it is not composable.

I must must call this function from several other composable functions.

So it needs to be not composable.

```
fun writeTextData(){

   val cx = LocalContext.current
   var textData = ""

   // Composes text data
   textData += ...
   ...

    FileWorks().writeText(cx, "setup", "setup", content = textData)

}
```

Comment: where is writeTextData called or being used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where `writeTextData` is being used, but why not just add a parameter to the function signature?

```
fun writeTextData(context: Context){

   ...
   ...
   ...

   FileWorks().writeText(context, "setup", "setup", content = textData)
}
```

Comment: I dont want use **@Composable
fun writeTextData(){**  I want to use just **fun writeTextData(){** that was the problem. :)

Comment: How is it used then? where is it being called? from another composable?

Comment: When it is not composable  **val cx = LocalContext.current** rises error. There are several composable functions changes data with textfield for example. When data change I want to call writeTextData() to save changes.

Comment: Yep it will not compile because it's a composable being called to a non-composable one, so where is `writeTextData(context: Context)` being called?

Comment: When writeTextData() is composable you can not call it from other composable functions. It needs to be just function.

Comment: How do you use `writeTextData()`? or where do you call `writeTextData()`?

Comment: val path = context.filesDir, how do you use filesdir without context then. If you dont use composable functions. You should call write text at every place text changed then it could be done but I wanted to do it at one place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249384/discussion-between-hope-and-z-y).